# If HEAD-HTTP-Requests only fetch the HTTP-Header, why my XHR-request has a reponseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, get, head

Today I researched about HTTP-methods and the differences between GET and HEAD in detail.

In theory I know, that HEAD only returns the HTTP header, not the HTTP body. Its useful to get information about ressources without downloading them completly.

I made a little Script using XHR to check out a HEAD-reques and tested it in Firefox 50.0.2.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYqGMQ

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
     alert("got response \n" + req.responseText); 
  }
}, false);

req.open("HEAD", location.href, true); // this is a HEAD-request, why I get a responseText?
req.send();
```

Why the HEAD-Request receives the complete data in the reponseText-property? I thought HEAD-Request will not receive any data of the body.

I can't see any difference between HEAD and GET.

Am I missing a point? I am using Firefox.

Comment: I tried different browsers (Chrome & Safari) and they have the behaviour I expect: no response body. I was using Firefox before. Probably thats a bug or something.

Comment: I made [a PHP script](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j1k3-zr6h) to [an API endpoint](http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/) I found online - the data returned from [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/curl_getinfo) reveals download size == 0 for the HEAD request and no body content is returned; I am not sure about why the XMLHttpRequest would still have the _responsetext_ property set - the MDN page for [XMLHttpRequest.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) doesn't appear to mention the state of that property with _HEAD_ requests...

Comment: Chrome and Safari work fine with XHR-HEAD-Requests. Only Firefox seems to send GET-identical HEAD-Requests with XHR. Really strange.